# How to fix "ValueError: Unknown extraction method 'jinja2'" error in Python ?( Jinja2 Internationalization ?)

Tags: python, jinja2, setuptools, pyramid, python-babel

I need to extract messages from jinja2 files from my pyramid web app, Babel has a three default extraction method (javascript, python, ignore). How can i add Jinja2 extraction method ?

All my packages are updated (pyramid, setuptools, babel, jinja2).

My setup.py file and setup.cfg file are in same directory and i've used `python setup.py develop` on terminal and occurred an error after some successful message extraction from py files, The Error => `ValueError: Unknown extraction method 'jinja2'`:

```
# from distutils.core import setup
# # from babel.messages import frontend

from setuptools import setup
import setuptools

setuptools.dist.Distribution(dict(setup_requires='Babel'))  # for message_extractors line below (else warnings / errors)

requires = [
    'pyramid', 'peewee', 'configparser', 'khayyam', 'Babel',
    'lingua', 'pyramid_redis_sessions', 'bcrypt', 'tornado', 'jinja2', 'pyramid-jinja2'
]

setup(name='Genetic',
      install_requires=requires,
      entry_points="""
      [paste.app_factory]
      main = Genetic:main
      """,
      author="Javad Asoodeh",
      author_email="##",
      message_extractors={'.': [
          ('Genetic/**.py', 'python', None),
          ('Genetic/**.jinja2', 'jinja2', {'input_encoding': 'utf-8'}),
          ('Genetic/template/base/**.jinja2', 'jinja2', {'input_encoding': 'utf-8'}),
          ('Genetic/templates/**.html', 'jinja2', {'input_encoding': 'utf-8'}),
          ('Genetic/templates/**.jinja2', 'jinja2', {'input_encoding': 'utf-8'}),
      ]},
      )
```

My Babel configuration file `setup.cfg` :

```
[jinja2: **/templates/**.jinja2]
extensions=jinja2.ext.i18n
encoding = utf-8

[compile_catalog]
directory = Genetic/locale
domain = Genetic
statistics = true

[extract_messages]
add_comments = TRANSLATORS:
output_file = Genetic/locale/Genetic.pot
width = 80
input_dirs = Genetic/templates

[init_catalog]
domain = Genetic
input_file = Genetic/locale/Genetic.pot
output_dir = Genetic/locale

[update_catalog]
domain = Genetic
input_file = Genetic/locale/Genetic.pot
output_dir = Genetic/locale
previous = true
```

Comment: did you try these?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046998/babel-doesnt-recognize-jinja2-extraction-method-for-language-support

Comment: yes I did, But i fixed error with reinstall jinja2 Library.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error with reinstall Jinja2 library and babel library manually using pip package manager.